# regexp_substr a numeric ratio within a string

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

How can I leverage the regexp_substr function (in redshift) to extract numeric ratios from a string?  Examples:

```
Product name 1:4 subtype name
10:5 product name
[5:1] product name
product name [1:15]
```

Would like to capture just the 1:4 portion of the text.

Thanks

Comment: Please make your sample data representative of the way it actually looks in your database. A one liner sample data is not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `regexp_substr()` like so:

```
regexp_substr(mycol, '[0-9]+:[0-9]+')
```

This extracts the (first) match of a pattern made if at least one digit, followed by a semi-colon, then at least one digit.